# Azure dashboard 'Save a copy' misleading

Tags: azureportal, azure-dashboard

When I work on my Azure custom dashboard(which is shared), I get a message asking me to 'Save a copy' as given below.

I have just one dashboard and it is shared.

1. Why should I save a copy?
2. If I save a copy, what would happen to the existing dashboard?
3. Why can't I just save the existing dashboard (instead of copy)?
4. Since it is shared, shouldn't it reflect the changes when I save?

It is difficult to check with others if they get to see the changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1."Save a Copy" is nothing but saving the changes that have been done to the existing dashboard and there will be no copy saved explicitly.

2.If there are any new changes made to the existing dashboard then when you click on save a copy  then new changes will be incorporated to the existing dashboard.

3.As mentioned earlier, it just saves the changes made to existing dashboard

4.Normally, the changes will be reflected to all the users who have access to the dashboard.

Please note access to resources is managed through role-based access control assignment and permissions are inherited from the subscription down to the resource. Giving access to a dashboard doesn’t automatically assign permissions to the resources shown on the dashboard. For more information about permissions to shared dashboards and role-based access control for resource, see [Share dashboards with role-based access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboard-share-access#understanding-access-control-for-dashboards)

Comment: Why bring in new terms? Just a 'Save'  button would do

Comment: yes, i agree with you, Save button would suffice. I would recommend to provide your feedback for the azure [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback)